# Hiding Extra Profiles when Manually Adding/Editing Registrant

Tags: civievent, custom-fields, profile

I have a site that has multiple different event types on it. Each of these event types have a different profile associated with the event.

The client has back-end access to CiviCRM and when they try to manually register a person for an event it shows all of the profiles, not just the one associated with the event. Some of these fields are required fields, so the client then has to put something in them to finish the registration or save the edit.

Is there a way to have all of the profiles that haven't been associated with an event type to not display in the back-end when editing or adding a registrant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah those are not profiles but custom data sets/fields.

Two tips:

1) Make sure that the custom data sets that you create are more specific than just on Participants -> configure it to also narrow down to a specific event.

2) Don't make the custom data fields within a custom data set required - but only make them required in the Profile - once you pull them in there. That way these fields are only required on pages that contain the profile.

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the Group of Custom Fields to be collapsed on first view, which will impact on the back end 'add a participation record' (which use the Group of Custom Fields) but not on the front facing 'registration' forms (which use the Profile).

This can help if you do have multiple Groups of Custom Fields showing on the same Entity or sub-Entity (eg Participant or Activity of Contact Type/sub-type)